# akka-cluster: actor not picking up a job

Tags: akka-cluster

I am using akka cluster for actor distribution, and struggling with an issue.

In my application, I have an actor, say 'engine' which processes a job. From configuration, I can set how many instances
of engine to be created on a node in the cluster. Engine receives job from an external system where I can disable a job, thus making corresponding engine idle(running, but not doing anything, and ready to accept a new available job).

I start 2 nodes(node 1, node 2), ie total 4 engines are running, each processing a job.

Now I disable a job, which makes one of the engine on , say node 1, idle and thus ready to accept  another job.

Now I stop node 2, thus entirely stopping engines running on it.

I expect that one of the job from node 2 is now picked from the idle engine on node 1.

But that doesnt happen.

But if I stop node 1 too and restart it, then I see both engines on it now executing jobs.

I am not really sure what can be the cause? Or where to start looking to debug the issue?

Comment: Are you using Akka cluster with Sharding?  Disabling a job means stopping a Actor or Stopping to produce job1 messages?

Comment: Disabling a job means stopping producing messages. Yes, sharding is used.

Comment: !Now I disable a job, which makes one of the engine on , say node 1, idle and thus ready to accept another job.
Can you explain it bit clear

Comment: So when a job is disabled, actor consuming messages for that job keeps running, but doing no processing. But if another job is available, this idle actor can start consuming messages from that job.

Comment: You are sayin 4 Actors (Engine) running in node 1,2.  You keep sending jobs to these Actors right? How you are sending the Jobs to Engine?. In Sharding you can send a message to an Actor by ActorName.  

Example If you send a job1 to ActorA (EngineA) if any thread available it will process the job1. If u send a message to a particular Actor No other Actor will pick the message.


Can you rephrase the Question more clearly how you sending jobs to Actor,How the Actors created little bit more clearly

Comment: can you eloborate the question